# What are strategies to store and give access to client-application specific setting on API server?

Tags: architecture, client-server, storage, key-value

I'm building a service which will consists of one API-server and many clients (mobile, web, desktop, etc). The problem I'm trying to solve is that each client might want to store some variable for each user, which is going to be available client-wide.

For example:

- Web client want to store that John likes his sidebar collapsed;
- Desktop client want to store that John completed his tutorial.

As it's better not to annoy user with tutorial again if he re-installs application or changes the browser I want to store these settings on server, also there might be any number of clients and I don't know in advance what kind of options they would need.

The question is, what are strategies to build this kind of storage? What would be the best way to isolate clients from each other? How would be the best to give access to clients to this data?

Comment: I would represent data in json format with three additional information: userId, clientTypeId, clientVersionId. Then store this in database and access by rest service.